# What do the last three 16 bit reports in this gamepad HID descriptor mean?

Tags: arduino, usb, driver, esp32, hid

I need some help understanding the last part of this usb hid report descriptor. It is rather straight forward for the most part, except for the last 3 fields of 16 bits (line 60 - 67). I am going to use this for what should be a rather simple arduino esp32 project. For this project I need to write a small device driver using [This](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) library.

```
Usage Page (Desktop),               ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
Logical Minimum (0),
Usage (Gamepad),                    ; Gamepad (05h, application collection)
Collection (Application),
    Report ID (1),
    Usage Page (Button),            ; Button (09h)
    Logical Minimum (0),
    Logical Maximum (1),
    Report Size (1),
    Report Count (10),
    Usage (01h),
    Usage (02h),
    Usage (04h),
    Usage (05h),
    Usage (07h),
    Usage (08h),
    Usage (0Eh),
    Usage (0Fh),
    Usage (09h),
    Usage (0Ch),
    Input (Variable),
    Usage Page (Consumer),          ; Consumer (0Ch)
    Report Count (6),
    Usage (Mute),                   ; Mute (E2h, on/off control)
    Usage (Volume Inc),             ; Volume increment (E9h, re-trigger control)
    Usage (Volume Dec),             ; Volume decrement (EAh, re-trigger control)
    Usage (Power),                  ; Power (30h, on/off control)
    Usage (AC Back),                ; AC back (0224h, selector)
    Usage (AC Home),                ; AC home (0223h, selector)
    Input (Variable),
    Usage Page (Desktop),           ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
    Usage (Hat Switch),             ; Hat switch (39h, dynamic value)
    Logical Maximum (7),
    Physical Minimum (0),
    Physical Maximum (270),
    Unit (Degrees),
    Report Size (4),
    Report Count (1),
    Input (Variable),
    Input (Constant, Variable),
    Usage (Pointer),                ; Pointer (01h, physical collection)
    Collection (Physical),
        Report Size (16),
        Report Count (4),
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (65535),
        Physical Minimum (0),
        Physical Maximum (65535),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Usage (Z),                  ; Z (32h, dynamic value)
        Usage (Rz),                 ; Rz (35h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Simulation),    ; Simulation controls (02h)
        Report Count (2),
        Usage (C5h),
        Usage (C4h),
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Application),
        Usage Minimum (01h),
        Usage Maximum (03h),
        Logical Maximum (65535),
        Report Count (3),
        Report Size (16),
        Output (Variable),
    End Collection,
End Collection,
```

It is a generic gamepad, but with rumble motors, so my first guess was that those are controls for the rumble feature on the device. They are declared as outputs which would support that guess. However, the usage types don't make sense for that use case at all and I don't see why you would need 3 reports of 16 bits to control that.

It also doesn't seem to be padding, since the total amount of bits comes up to 164, which is rather random, and you don't need to declare usage types for that. It is also declared as an output, which is strange for padding.

Can anybody help me understand this? I have read the hid documentation, but could not find any clear answers.

There was a request for the raw hex code:

```
003:011:000:DESCRIPTOR         1650199607.153697
 05 01 15 00 09 05 A1 01 85 01 05 09 15 00 25 01
 75 01 95 0A 09 01 09 02 09 04 09 05 09 07 09 08
 09 0E 09 0F 09 09 09 0C 81 02 05 0C 95 06 09 E2
 09 E9 09 EA 09 30 0A 24 02 0A 23 02 81 02 05 01
 09 39 25 07 35 00 46 0E 01 65 14 75 04 95 01 81
 02 81 03 09 01 A1 00 75 10 95 04 15 00 26 FF FF
 35 00 46 FF FF 09 30 09 31 09 32 09 35 81 02 05
 02 95 02 09 C5 09 C4 81 02 C0 A1 01 19 01 29 03
 26 FF FF 95 03 75 10 91 02 C0 C0 05 01 09 02 A1
 01 85 02 09 01 A1 00 05 09 19 01 29 03 25 01 75
 01 95 03 81 02 05 09 09 05 95 01 81 02 75 04 81
 01 05 01 09 30 09 31 15 81 25 7F 75 10 95 02 81
 06 C0 C0 06 DE FF 09 01 A1 01 05 FF 19 01 29 40
 85 FD 15 00 25 FF 95 40 75 08 81 02 C0 06 DE FF
 09 03 A1 01 19 01 29 40 85 FC 95 40 75 08 B1 02
 C0
```

Comment: It's impossible to say because the last Collection is not identified by a Usage Page and a Usage of type CA. Also, it seems to contain a few other errors - e.g. the hat switch has 7 states and max 270 degrees (it's usually 3 * 90 degrees = 270 max or 7 * 45 degrees = 315 max). Can you post the raw hex code for this report descriptor?

Comment: @aja That's rather strange. It is an nvidia controller, so i wouldn't expect such mistakes from such a large company. I have added the hex code to the post. I used the usbhid-dump tool from [this](https://github.com/DIGImend/usbhid-dump) repo

Comment: Yes even major vendors get it wrong occasionally. Report descriptor encoding is difficult. I have written my own decoder however at https://github.com/abend0c1/hidrdd which I used to check the above hex. The application collection in your example is nested within another application collection - which is not legal. Even if you moved it into its own collection you would still need to supply a usage page and an Application Collection (CA) usage code to make sense of the usages (1, 2 and 3) contained within it.

Comment: They also appear to have fallen into a newbie trap of trying to encode a LOGICAL_MAXIMUM of 32767 (26 FF FF) as -1 (25 FF) - leading to the LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (-1) being less than the LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0) - which is not legal.

Comment: They also forgot to reset PHYSICAL units when they are no longer needed - so those units apply to all remaining fields because physical units are GLOBAL items and are not reset when the next MAIN item is encountered. They've also used a reserved usage page 0x00FF (05 FF) when they probably meant to use a vendor usage page e.g. 0xFF00 (06 00 FF). Basically it's a mess IMHO.

Comment: Wow it does seem so. I expected more from such a large company. Thank you for this kind clarification! It seems like you know quite a lot.

Comment: @aja i have also found that another hid decoder parses the same hex differently for that -1. It reports that it should be 65535 instead. Is this more correct?

Comment: I don't think so. The spec says "If both the Logical Minimum and Logical Maximum extents are defined as positive values (0 or greater) then the report field can be assumed to be an unsigned value. Otherwise, all integer values are signed values represented in2’s complement format."

Comment: This means if you define a logical maximum using 25 FF then it means -1 regardless of the report length (field width) in bits.  If you want +32767 then you need to encode that as a 4-byte number using 27 FF FF 00 00. That's my take on it anyway.

Comment: Yep, my earlier comment about 26 FF FF  is not correct either (it still means -1). Even I get confused!

Comment: But logical minimum is 0 be default, so that means both are positive and thus it should be interpreted as an unsigned int and not as a signed one. This would make sense as 65535 is the maximum value of a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: But 25 FF, 26 FF FF, and 27 FF FF FF FF all mean - 1 regardless of the number bits in the field (report size). If you need to specify 255 then the only two ways to do that are 26 FF 00 and 27 FF 00 00 00. The last 2 bits of the item code specifies the length of the item value - which can be 1, 2 or 4 bytes - so the parser knows how to interpret the 2's complement item value that follows.